# How can I stop or pause Quartz.Net when I puase topshelf service?

Tags: service, quartz.net, topshelf

How can I stop or pause Quartz.Net when I pause topshelf service?

Currently at all examples, - registration is outside of start/stop methods:

```
factory.Service<IServiceHost>(sc =>
{
  sc.ConstructUsing(s => new ServiceHost());
  sc.WhenStarted((s, host) => s.Start(host));
  sc.WhenStopped(s => s.Stop());
  sc.WhenPaused(s => s.Pause());
  sc.WhenContinued(s => s.Continue());

  sc.ScheduleQuartzJob(...)
}
```

Comment: What speaks against `Scheduler.Shutdown()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program.cs

```
        HostFactory.Run(factory =>
        {
            factory.UseNLog();
            factory.UseAutofacContainer(Container);
            factory.Service<ServiceHost>(service =>
            {
                service.ConstructUsingAutofacContainer();
                service.WhenStarted((sc, hc) => sc.Start(hc));
                service.WhenStopped((sc, hc) =>
                {
                    Container.Dispose();
                    return sc.Stop(hc);
                });

                service.ScheduleQuartzJob(cfg => JobConfigurator.GetConfigurationForJob<DataImportJob>(cfg, Settings.Default.RecurrentTimeout));

                factory.RunAsLocalSystem().StartAutomaticallyDelayed().EnableServiceRecovery(sr =>
            {
                sr.OnCrashOnly();
                sr.RestartService(0);
                sr.SetResetPeriod(1);
            }).EnableShutdown();
        });
```

ServiceControl.cs:

```
public class ServiceHost : ServiceControl
{
    private readonly IScheduler _scheduler;

    public CdcServiceHost(IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        Ensure.Argument.NotNull(scheduler);
        _scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        if (!_scheduler.IsStarted)
        {
            _scheduler.Start();
        }

        Logger.Log.Debug("Service was started");
        return true;
    }

    public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        Logger.Log.Debug("Stopping scheduler");
        _scheduler.Shutdown(true);

        Logger.Log.Debug("Service was stopped");
        return true;
    }
}
```